# Embedded ldap growing huge in Weblogic and causing high GC

Tags: java, ldap, weblogic, weblogic12c

Folks have anyone come across this issue where Embedded ldap growing huge in Weblogic and causing high GC which in-turn is crashing the application.

Can anyone help if something similar to this scenario was faces prior for anyone and the same was fixed.

Scenario>

If embedded LDAP grows beyond 450MB, application crashes by causing high GC.

Comment: which version of WLS are you using ?, do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Its WLS 12.2.1.3

Comment: WebLogic server has suffered many issues with the embedded ldap with previous versions. Check you are using the last PSU for your version.
Do you have any exception/error raised by WebLogic when it crashes ?

Comment: Nothing as such, all the patches were applied though. What oracle recommends it to use RDBMS instead of Embedded LDAP. Just wondering if anyone else has faced this kind of an issue previously.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set the size of LDAP:
From original [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/SECMG/ldap.htm#SECMG328):

The data file and change log file used by the embedded LDAP server can potentially grow quite large. You can configure maximum sizes for these files with the following `weblogic.Server` command line arguments:

> ```
> -Dweblogic.security.ldap.maxSize=<max bytes>
> ```
>
> which limits the size of the data file used by the embedded LDAP server. When the data
> file exceeds the specified size, WebLogic Server eliminates from the
> data file space occupied by deleted entries.
>
> ```
> -Dweblogic.security.ldap.changeLogThreshold=<number of entries>
> ```
>
> which limits the size of the change log file used by the embedded LDAP
> server. When the change log file exceeds the specified number of
> entries, WebLogic Server truncates the change log by removing all
> entries that have been sent to all Managed Servers.

Comment: Thanks, tried these but this is not helping either.

Answer (score 0):

Stop all managed servers and the Admin Server.
Locate and rename/remove the following files:
<DOMAIN_HOME>/servers/AdminServer/data/ldap/ldapfiles/changelog.data
<DOMAIN_HOME>/servers/AdminServer/data/ldap/ldapfiles/changelog.index

This can be applied in the start-up scripts of the servers as mentioned below:
JAVA_OPTIONS="${SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.security.ldap.changeLogThreshold=10000"
These parameters can also be implemented in the WebLogic Console:
1.Go to AdminServer -> ServerStart -> Arguments.
2.Provide the parameters.

Restart the Admin Server and the managed servers.

But most of the cases these values are not taking effect and the size will keep on increase :-)

Comment: phaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa